# How to match a regex expression only if a word is present before or after

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm really struggling with some regex. I've had a good look at similar questions and I can't work out why it's not working!

I'm trying to match the string 'ok' when it is preceded by 4 digits ((?<=\d{4}\s)ok) but only when the word 'devo' appears anywhere before or anywhere after in the string

```
text_to_search="devo XXXXXXXXXX 9999 ok ferial blabla" 
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=devo)((?<=\d{4}\s)ok)|((?<=\d{4}\s)ok)(?=devo)")
matches = pattern.finditer (text_to_search)
[print (x) for x in matches]
```

This does not return any matches... if i try with:

```
text_to_search=" XXXXXXXXXX 9999 ok ferial blabla devo"
```

it does not work either.

Just for clarity, the two examples above should match, but if i take another example like :

```
text_to_search=" XXXXXXXXXX 9999 ok ferial blabla"
```

then this should not produce a match since 'devo' is not present..

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `(?<=devo)` means immediately preceded by `devo`. For what you are describing it should be something like `(?<=devo.*)`, but this is not supported by python `re`.

Comment: On the other hand, you can easily split check for `devo` presence, and check for ok, only if it is present.

Comment: If you only expect a single match, you can use `re`: `^(?=.*devo).*\d{4}\s+ok`. The rest depends on what you do with `ok`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing for the *anywhere* before or after part. Try this

```
(?<=devo).*((?<=\d{4}\s)ok)|((?<=\d{4}\s)ok).*(?=devo)
```

But I think the lookarounds are overkill here. A much simpler

```
(devo.*\d{4}\sok)|(\d{4}\sok.*devo)
```

might work as well.

Comment: thank you so much it works, can you please explain it, it seems the .* is fixing it?

Comment: It's a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to basically match anything. `.` is anything and `*` means "any number of that before. You might want to try a tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QmDpqk/1) to get a detailed technical description.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the regex easier by just checking if `devo` is in the string first:

```py
import re

text_to_search=" XXXXXXXXXX 9999 ok ferial blabla devo" 

ok = re.compile(r'(?<=\d{4}\s)ok')

if 'devo' in text_to_search:
    matches = [m.string for m in ok.finditer(text_to_search)]
else:
    print('no match')
    matches = []
```